# Incredibly slow and intermitting internet connection on a private network with custom DNS Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, google-chrome, internet, dns

I am experiencing a very weird phenomenon on a Lenovo Thinkpad E15 with `Ubuntu 20.04`, specs:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               pc@user 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: 20YGCTO1WW ThinkPad E15 Gen 3 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.13-051513-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 55 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2250 (dpkg) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 1.800GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Device 164c 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2236MiB / 6823MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

The fact is the following. As long as I'm on every public network, also at home, I have no problem surfing the web. While at my laboratory, which has his own DNS and custom settings for the network I am not really able to work with Internet.

Indeed, both on Ethernet and WiFi, I keep expeciencing either a complete fault of the line with the Chrome browser stating problems like (every time a different one)

- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG
- DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

either a terribly slow connection with intermittent peaks of going down.
The fact is that, sometimes if you wait in the end the pages are loading. As a first initial guess I would say that something with the DNS setting is completely broken so that they work, but in the middle something bad happens. When the pages are loading I have the full power network and everything is fine, but this only last for few moments and after a little bit of surfing I'm back with problems.

I basically looked at all the possible solutions online I found by googling and askubutuing all the errors, but it seems that in most cases are solved by using Google DNS `8.8.8.8`, which in my case did not work at all. This I suspect because of the custom DNS of the institution. In the end I found myself having modified all possible files `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/dhcp/dhcpclient.conf` and a buch of stuff like that and I feel that going on with solutions which are not intended for my problem could potentially ruin my (already illed) configurations.

Notice that in the very same room there are other 3 pc with `Ubuntu 20.04` and another one with `Ubuntu 21.04`, that means something strange is happening with the only pc is not working, which in turn means that either there are illed configurations either the pc has some internal problem. I would exlude the last optionsince is a completely brand new laptop.

Any idea on what can I do? I'm sure that this question needs lot of improvements in terms of configuration files that i have but I don't really know where to start, so if someone has advices for posting potentially interesting configurations files, host files, and all of this just let me know.

Comment: You're not using a *supported* Ubuntu *focal* (20.04) kernel, have you tried a *supported* rather than *testing* kernel?

Comment: Not really, do you recommend downgrading to a _supported_ version?

Comment: By using the *testing* kernel, you're helping testing, however if issues are encountered you're somewhat on your own as that's what *testing* kernels are for. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will get the 5.15 kernel when it reaches 20.04.5; but currently it's only 20.04.4 (meaning 5.4 for GA kernel, 5.13 for HWE..)  You can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for help on reporting your issues with your *testing* grade kernel.

Comment: You really don't have enough RAM. However, tell us what special settings your lab network requires. Also show us what files you modified to accommodate. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `resolvectl status`.

Comment: Install `iputils-tracepath`, then do `tracepath www.ebay.com`. Edit the output into your question. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks to all your replies, I finally decided to completely erase the PC and brand install Ubuntu 22.04. Next Monday I will be back in laboratory, if the problem was the software or some settings i'll close the question, but if, as i fear, is something to deal with the pc I'll edit the question with updates.